# Make my Classified site Multicity Platform

Tags: php

I have a classified website and I am using a single script for each city and Im looking to use one script that will allow users to switch cities. If this is possible please let me know any help would be greatly appreciated Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here are a few example approaches:

- You can add a parameter such as `?city=foo` to the URL. This parameter can be read by the script.
- You can include the city as part of the location `http://yoursite.com/foo/` and use some URL rewrite magic to ensure that the same script gets all the requests.
- You can store the user's preferred city in a cookie which your script reads.

Comment: Thanks Mark for Answering, The script is written in PHP and running mysql for database. So I can do this and only have one database and one script? How could i implement that into the script and administrator panel. Im kinda new with this stuff. Thanks for your Help.

Comment: @cameron: Your should edit your question (or repost) with some **relevant parts** of your code. Otherwise it's impossible to answer without resorting to broad descriptions and guesscode.

Comment: hi @Mark Byers, can i use city name as like `http://foo.yoursite.com/` using rewriting or i have create subdomain for this..?? I hope you got my point becos i am lil bit slow in english.. :) please reply..